# List of toast cannot be removed on uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I tried to create a toast notification with the custom audio. While the program running, the program can display the toast. I added list of toast on ListBox too. It works smoothly for displaying notification, but it cannot remove the toast from list box.

This is the code for adding toast:

```
public void Add(ref ListBox display, string value, string value2, TimeSpan occurs)
{
    DateTime when = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,
        occurs.Hours, occurs.Minutes, occurs.Seconds);

    if (when > DateTime.Now)
    {
        // Construct the toast content
        ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
        {
            //toast display here
        };

        //audio 

        // And create the toast notification
        ScheduledToastNotification toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml(), when);
        // And then send the toast       
        toast.Id = random.Next(1, 100000000).ToString();
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(toast);            
        display.Items.Add(new Item { Id = toast.Id, Content = value, Time = when.ToString() });
    }
}
```

This is for removing toast from listbox:

```
public void Remove(ListBox display)
{
    if (display.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        ToastNotifier notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        notifier.RemoveFromSchedule(notifier.GetScheduledToastNotifications().Where(
            p => p.Id.Equals(((Item)display.SelectedItem).Id)).SingleOrDefault());
        display.Items.RemoveAt(display.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use find item in the list box and try to remove

Comment: You said that "it cannot remove the toast from list box". Does that mean that you get an Exception from trying it? Or that the ListBox still shows the toast, despite it being removed?

Comment: Also, setting the audio to the toast has nothing to do with your problem. Could you please remove that from the code, so we can read it more easily?

Comment: Sorry, I found my wrong code, so I already resolved it. Thanks ...

Comment: There's no need to pass the ListBox by ref.

Comment: @OliviaOlgaClarissa So either post the answer yourself, if you think it can help People From The Future. Else, delete your question.